# jquery simplemodal error on IE8 for removeExpression

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, simplemodal

I am using `jquery` simple plugin for my modal popup script, it is working on Firefox and Chrome but IE8 returns following error.

```
Message: Not implemented
Line: 16
Char: 133
Code: 0
URI: ...mysite/js/simplemodal-1.4.4/js/jquery.simplemodal.js
```

At this file location I see following codes

```
**f.removeExpression("height"),f.removeExpression("width"),........**
```

Anybody can help me how can I solve this issue,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its tough to answer that way, can you provide some more code base above and below it. What is f?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7169505